# Ef Core 6.0 Add InitialCreate fails

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Ef Core 6.0, and when I try to run the first migration using

"dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate"  I get the following error.

Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String language, Boolean nullable, String[] remainingArguments)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor(String[] remainingArguments)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still have this issue but in case you do. Try adding reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` to your project where db context is defined and that should resolve it.

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0"/>`